# variable issue in mysqli string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

this is the code

```
if($_POST['submit']) {

$rid = $_GET['rid'];
$award = $_GET['award'];
$award_id = $_GET['award_id'];
$member_id = $_GET['member_id'];

$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$dbprefix."clanawards_requests SET maa_status = '3' WHERE maa_request_id = '$rid'");
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$dbprefix."clanawards_members SET '".$award."' = '1' WHERE maa_member_id = '$member_id'");
```

the problem is in this line

```
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$dbprefix."clanawards_members SET '".$award."' = '1' WHERE maa_member_id = '$member_id'");
```

to be precise `SET '".$award."' = '1'`

`'".$award."'` is a column name and a variable and everything else works but this part of the code is not updating.

what i need to know is how to get the variable to work in this mysqli string.

Comment: how about if you say $sql="create your update string here"  ... then echo it to see how awful it looks

Comment: ^^^^ so much easier to debug this way

Comment: and what would that column name be exactly; `column-1`? `column 1`? `column 'xxx'`? `roman gods temple column`?

Comment: Ugly variable nesting, no `$_GET[]` filtering, setting integers as strings, mixing quote types. Oh boy.

Comment: column name would be Testing Award. i guess i can try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"column name would be Testing Award"*

You have to wrap that column name in ticks

```
SET `$award` = '1'
```

and not in quotes since it contains a space.

MySQL should have thrown you an syntax error: (consult Error checking methods below).

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Either that, or rename your column to contain an underscore.

I.e.: `Testing_Award`.

Do not use a hyphen, as MySQL would interpret `Testing-Award` as Testing minus Award, resulting in a syntax error, unless using backticks.

You should also use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

You're wide open to SQL injection.

---

**Error checking methods:**

Example:

```
$res = $mysqli->query($result);

if ($mysqli->error) {
    try {    
        throw new Exception("MySQL error $mysqli->error <br> Query:<br> $query", $mysqli->errno);    
    } catch(Exception $e ) {
        echo "Error No: ".$e->getCode(). " - ". $e->getMessage() . "<br >";
        echo nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
```

or:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $result);

if (!$result)
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

else{ echo "Success."; }
```

Ideally, using `mysqli_affected_rows()` will give you a better result, if the query was truly successful.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: i would use prepared statements but my coding skill isn't that high

Comment: @NukerViper It's not that hard really. Here are a few links you can look into.  PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php - couple of days and you'll be up and running in no time ;-)

Comment: Drive-by downvote, have a great day at church today. Thanks for the lovely Sunday surprise. Oh, and if you care to enlighten us with your almighty given power, we'll be more than happy to listen. Sounds like someone with "no common sense" to me.